# How do I split a file each time a regular expression occurs?

Tags: gawk

I'm trying to get gawk to split a text file into a different file each time a paragraph contains an occurrence of a code of the form "7-04/PNLP-000001". So, for instance, if the original text file contains the following:

> Proposición no de Ley 7-04/PNLP-000009, relativa a la línea Ave Sevilla-Córdoba-Madrid.
> La señora PRESIDENTA
> Proposición no de Ley 7-04/PNLP-000001, relativa a la restitución y mejora de los derechos y la cobertura social de los trabajadores del medio rural andaluz.
> La señora PRESIDENTA

I would like to get a file with this content:

> Proposición no de Ley 7-04/PNLP-000009, relativa a la línea Ave Sevilla-Córdoba-Madrid.
> La señora PRESIDENTA

and another with this content:

> Proposición no de Ley 7-04/PNLP-000001, relativa a la restitución y mejora de los derechos y la cobertura social de los trabajadores del medio rural andaluz.
> La señora PRESIDENTA

I'm trying to to this with this code:

```
gawk '
        /^\n.+[0-9]\-[0-9]{2}\/.+\-[0-9]{6}$/
        {if (p) close (p)
        p = sprintf("split%05i.txt", ++i) }
            { print > p; }
    ' input.txt
```

However, this just creates one file per line, whatever its content. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
awk '/[0-9]-[0-9]{2}\/[[:upper:]]+-[0-9]{6}/ {
       if (file) close (file)
       file = sprintf("split%05i.txt", ++i)
     }
     file {print > file}' input.txt
```

You want the `{ if... }` code block to be run for the lines that match the `[0-9]...` pattern, so, it should be on the same line as the `/.../`.

The second code block `{print > file}` is to be run for every record as long as `file` is set, using `file` as the condition.

Having `\n` in your pattern here doesn't make sense as each record that `awk` processes in turn is the contents of each line (as the default record separator (`RS`) is `\n`), so a record is never going to contain a newline character. You also don't want to anchor your regexp here (`^` and `$`).

I've replaced your `.+` with `[[:upper:]]+` so as to be more specific. With `.+`, it would match on `blah 5-10/2 blah blah €1000000` for instance. You may need to adapt depending on what you want to accept in place of `PNLP`.

Note that it also matches on `blah 1234-56/XX-1234567890 blah` as that does contain a string that matches the pattern (see part in bold).

I've removed the `g` in `gawk` as that code is not `gawk` specific. However note that there are still a few awk implementations that don't support the `{2}`/`{6}` operators above (even though that's a POSIX requirement), so if you know `gawk` is going to be available, you might as well use it to make sure it works.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:
`perl -ne 'my $fh="/dev/stdout"; if(/7-04\/PNLP-(\d+)/) { close $fh; open($fh,">/path/to/outputfiles/file$1"); } ; print $fh $_;' < /path/to/inputfile`